# JavaScript knockoutjs, set nested object value doesn't update Html?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm using knockout 3.3.0. Assume I have a model as the following:

[image: knockout model]

As you can see There are two nested objects, `DeviceStatistics` and `Product`.
At first they are OK and work fine and update HTML.
I assign the new values to these objects as the following:

```
window.KoEntityModel.EntityModel.DeviceStatistics = ko.mapping.fromJS(newJsonModel);
```

It's OK without any problems, but knockout doesn't update(change) HTML
Whereas, chrome console shows `window.KoEntityModel.EntityModel.DeviceStatistics` is observable:

[image: knockout nested model]

How can I fix it?

Comment: well you should use `window.KoEntityModel.EntityModel.DeviceStatistics(ko.mapping.fromJS(newJsonModel));` . `=` will update observable but not html . alternatively u can call valueHasMuated if you use `=`

Comment: @supercool: if I use your code error `Uncaught TypeError: window.KoEntityModel.EntityModel.DeviceStatistics is not a function` occurred and it's true, as you can see in Model it's not a function

Comment: my bad i see it now its a `object` right . is there any chance you can make `DeviceStatistics and Product` as observable and try assigning the same way as above . object does not give us 2 way binding flexibility .

Comment: Well, I create these models with `ko.mapping.fromJS()`, Actually they were serialized c# class that converted to `ko` model with `ko.mapping.fromJS()`, So how I can change them to `observable` objects

Comment: @supercool, unfortunately no, Bu I rate it.

Comment: it's sad to hear . so did you got your issue resolved ? tough i have gave you working sample . if anything we can help . get back on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
We have to update a knockoutJs view model with the following code:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(newDataInJson, {}, knocoutJsViewModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

well to convert `object` into `function` you need to do something like below

**viewModel:**

```
var fromserver = {
  'device': {
    'one': 'onevalue'
  },
  'product': {
    'prod': 'prodone'
  },
  'name': 'supercool'
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.device = ko.observable();
  self.prod = ko.observable();
  ko.mapping.fromJS(fromserver, {}, self); //this converts object into function & keeps the other prop's coming from server intact .
};
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

working sample fiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/28080/)** shows the modified data .